# Is there a way to specify a leftover queue in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to define a binding between an exchange (direct or topic) and a queue so that the queue receives only those messages that are sent to the routing keys that have no explicit binding with any other queue?

E.g. there is an exchange X and queues A and B. The queue A is bound with 'black' and 'white' binding keys. The queue B is defined as a leftover queue (if it is possible at all, which is the point of my question). So when we send a message to the exchange X with either 'black' or 'white' routing key, then it is delivered to the queue A. If we send a message to the exchange X with any other routing key then it is delivered to the queue B only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use RabbitMQ's [Alternate Exchange](http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html#alternate-exchange) feature. That's exactly what it has been designed to do.

Comment: I am a little bit conscious that it is an extension to the protocol. But what the hell, we won't be using any other AMQP implementation but RabbitMQ anyway. So, thanks a lot!